# Determinant Algebra computing

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Let $A, B \in M_3 (\mathbb{R})$, two invertible matrices such that $B^TA^{-1}= 2I_3$ and $ABA^T= I_3$.

How can I prove that $\det A + \det B = 9/2$?
Thanks!

Comment: Use Latex here for mathematics

Comment: where do I get it from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

$$|B|=|B^t|\;,\;\;\text{so}\;\; B^tA^{-1}=2I_3\implies|B^tA^{-1}|=\frac{|B|}{|A|}=2^3=8$$

But also

$$ABA^t=I_3\implies |ABA^t|=|A|^2|B|=1$$

So you have an easy system

$$\begin{cases}|B|=8|A|\\{}\\|A|^2|B|=1\end{cases}$$

Well, solve it...:)